# set same height for two divs which are not siblings of each other

Tags: html, css

I have two divs which are not sibling of each other. I have to set the height of both of them same in every case (i.e, even if one of them grows in height other re-sizes itself accordingly).

I have seen these two approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/sdsgW/

http://jsfiddle.net/VkPmg/2/

but both of these are for the sibling elements.

I have tried this http://jsfiddle.net/ders/z1f6bLop/

Still it is applicable only when I am using class= "row". And doesn't work without it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="c1" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="cl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col, .cl {
    display: table-cell;
       padding: 1em;
    border: solid;
}
```

Any solutions?

**Edit:- Interested in knowing the exact way of setting height of two divs same (because my both the divs are in different files, but are on the same html page)**

Comment: is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/z1f6bLop/1/ ? it's without the `class="row"` element

Comment: I can't understand why your "Edit" wasn't added to the question in the first place? .. This doesn't change the css/script and how it has to be, to me it is actually a whole new question, which have little to do with styling. ... Please edit your question and ask a new one which could be like "How to merge html fragments in 2 different files which need to share the same parent and css".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When use a `table-cell` you should use a `table` (sometimes even a `table-row`) to get expected result a cross browsers. So either you use the `body` as your `table` or a wrapper, like the "row" you used. Same with flex, as in your sample links, it needs a parent for the column children. If not, you need to use script to calculate each height and set the same value for the two.

Here is a sample using table/table-cell

```css
.tbl {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.cl {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
    
    <div class="col">
        <div class="cl" >
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
        <div class="cl">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
     </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is that the two divs are in different files.

Comment: If the elements apear on the same page, the css rule will be applied as soon as the browser is done parsing HTML content. So having the elements in different files , should not make any difference..

Comment: @rk11501 Then I need to know how those 2 files look like and "how"/"with what" they are loaded.